# Can the list section shown in Day view in Calendar removed?

Tags: macos, calendar

Now I've upgraded to Mountain Lion, when I look at Calendar in Day view, there's a ruddy great list in the middle of the window. I have 30 subscribed calendars that I need to be able to see and the list is not at all helpful.

As it only shows in Day view, can I change Week view to be a week of one day?

Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I think you are out of luck when it comes to this. Like most Apps that comes with OS X there isn't much space for customizing the UI.